# Showing total product count of a category in big commerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Does anyone know how can we show count of total product from a particular category  in big commerce please? i know how to show all products but showing total number of products from a category is not something that i could figure out. 
If someone have done it before, please let me know.

Comment: Are you working with blueprint or Stencil?

Answer (score 1):

If using the API:

***@see https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products#get-a-product-count***

---

**HTTP GET** /api/v2/products/count?category=value

---

**Browser** 
https://username:password@store_url.com/api/v2/products/count?category=value

---

**Curl** 
curl -u username:password https://store_url.com/api/v2/products/count?category=value

Comment: IS it possible even if I have access to .html files only? I was expecting to get it using jquery or javascript only :-(

Comment: I tried like this  ` $.get( "http://mystore.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/count?category=value ", function( data ) {

  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
}); ` But it is showing error like this  "The connection is not secure. API requests must be made via HTTPS" and the problem is i want to do this over http , not over https. Thanks

Comment: Well, you wouldn't want to make API requests from JS because then you would expose the username/password. I would rather host the API code on your own server, and then you can access it via JS from your store. .... What exactly are you trying to do though? What is the end goal.

Comment: This worked for me https://username:password@store_url.com/api/v2/products/count?category=value